# Initialization of non-primitive static data type within class in C++

Tags: c++, qt, class, static-members

```
#include <QQueue>
#include <QString>

class   Util {
public:

    static QQueue<QString> links;

    Util() {
    }
};

    Util::links.enqueue("hello world");
```

How can I do that?

Comment: perhaps http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlist.html#QList-3 could be useful

Answer (score 2):

You could initialise it with the result of a function:

```
QQueue<QString> make_links() {
    QQueue<QString> queue;
    queue.enqueue("hello world");
    return queue;
}

QQueue<QString> Util::links = make_links();
```

I'm not familiar with QT, but one might hope that they are adding support for C++11 initialiser lists, in which case you'd be able to initialise it as:

```
QQueue<QString> Util::links {"hello world"};
```

(UPDATE: according to the link in Shahbaz's comment, you can indeed do that if you are using C++11).

Answer (score 1):

Try using a static member function:

```
#include <QQueue>
#include <QString>

class   Util {
public:

    static QQueue<QString>& links() {
      static QQueue<QString> instance;
      static bool is_init = false;
      if(!is_init) {
        instance.enqueue("hello world");
        is_init = true;
      }
      return instance;
    }

    Util() {
    }
};
```

In C++11 QQueue seems to support initializer lists, as Shahbaz has said:

```
QQueue<QString> Util::links = {"hello world"};
```

Comment: In a multi-threaded program, you'll need to make sure you initialise it before allowing multiple threads to access it. You don't have that problem with a static object.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Yeah, a static member function isn't that good of a solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use static initializer object for all such cases:

header file:

```
#include <QQueue>
#include <QString>

class   Util {
public:

    static QQueue<QString> links;

    Util() {
    }
};
```

cpp file:

```
namespace {
    struct StaticInitializer {
        StaticInitializer() {
            Util::links.enqueue("hello world");
        }
    } initializer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You initialize as usual, in the global scope:

```
QQueue<QString> Util::links;
```

or

```
QQueue<QString> Util::links(1); // with constructor parameters if necessary
```

Comment: Except `"hello world"` is not there! Also, [QQueue](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qqueue.html) doesn't have that constructor